# Problem in merge condition in oracle when merging two tables

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sql-update, sql-merge

I have a table which has data as:

```
id  payor_name
---------------
1   AETNA
2   UMR
3   CIGNA
4   METLIFE
4   AETNAU
5   ktm
6   ktm
```

`Id` and `payor_name` are two columns.So,

My expected output is:

```
   id  payor_name
    ---------------
    1   AETNA
    2   UMR
    3   CIGNA
    4   METLIFE
    4   AETNAU
    6   ktm  ...> I want to change the id of this row to be 6 from 5.
    6   ktm
```

I want one to one mapping between id and payor_name.So,this is what I tried:

```
MERGE INTO offc.payor_collec A
USING (select id from offc.payor_collec where payor_name in( 
select payor_name from offc.payor_collec group by payor_name having count(distinct id)>=2)) B
ON (A.id=B.id)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET A.id=B.id
```

But when I compiled I got error as:

```
Error at line 1
ORA-38104: Columns referenced in the ON Clause cannot be updated: "A"."ID"
```

Id is number where as payor_name is varchar2.

How can I achieve this result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MERGE` works, but slightly different than your code.

```
SQL> select * from test;

        ID PAYOR
---------- -----
         1 aetna
         2 umr
         5 ktm
         6 ktm

SQL> merge into test t
  2    using (select max(t1.id) id,
  3                  t1.payor_name
  4           from test t1
  5           group by t1.payor_name
  6          ) x
  7    on (x.payor_name = t.payor_name)
  8  when matched then update set
  9    t.id = x.id;

4 rows merged.

SQL> select * from test;

        ID PAYOR
---------- -----
         1 aetna
         2 umr
         6 ktm
         6 ktm

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a correlated subquery:

```
UPDATE PAYOR_COLLEC pc
  SET pc.ID = (SELECT MAX(pc2.ID)
                 FROM PAYOR_COLLEC pc2
                 WHERE pc2.PAYOR_NAME = pc.PAYOR_NAME)
```

[dbfiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=0bc82862be09a8893e81c674f0552cde)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `MERGE` statement, as you tried and as Littlefoot has shown.

You can also use a correlated subquery as Bob Jarvis has shown, but that will be quite inefficient.

Many Oracle developers are unaware that you can also update through a join. Worse, there are many who say "there is no such thing in Oracle."

In your problem, you need to join your table to an aggregate query (picking just the max id for each payor_name) and the join is on the `group by` column in the aggregate. This already guarantees that the join column will be unique in the right-hand table; that is all Oracle needs to allow the update through join.

Here is a complete example, starting with the `create table` statement, then the `update` and then showing the table after the update. Note that I don't need any constraints (like primary key, not null, unique, etc.) or indexes on the base table. If they do exist, so much the better, but the solution works in the most general case.

```
create table t (id, payor_name) as
  select 1, 'AETNA'   from dual union all
  select 2, 'UMR'     from dual union all
  select 3, 'CIGNA'   from dual union all
  select 4, 'METLIFE' from dual union all
  select 4, 'AETNAU'  from dual union all
  select 5, 'ktm'     from dual union all
  select 6, 'ktm'     from dual;

Table T created.

update
  (
    select id, payor_name, max_id
    from   t inner join 
           (select max(id) as max_id, payor_name from t group by payor_name)
           using (payor_name)
  )
set id = max_id where id != max_id
;

1 row updated.

select * from t;

   ID PAYOR_NAME
----- ----------
    1 AETNA  
    2 UMR    
    3 CIGNA  
    4 METLIFE
    4 AETNAU 
    6 ktm    
    6 ktm
```

Notice the `where` clause at the end of the `update` statement, too. You don't want to update rows to their pre-existing value; that will still generate undo and redo data (although I understand that Oracle has changed that in more recent versions - it now doesn't generate undo and redo unless a row did indeed change). I assume ID is NOT NULL - otherwise you should rewrite the `where` clause as

```
where decode(id, max_id, 0) is null
```

or equivalent